# adding background image with html while adding css attributes

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I have a Django project and I want to add a background image to the HTML template. I have the following code:

```
<body class="standard-background-color standard-font-family" background="{% static '/images/background1.jpg' %}">
```

It displays the original size which is 5300 X 3100 or something like that. I want to change the image size for the background image but when I apply css to the body tag the images size is not changing. How can I change the image size to 1920 x 1080...

Comment: _... but when i apply css to the body tag the images size is not change_ , how and where do you do that? Add the relevant code to reproduce the problem

Comment: you have to use a photoshop and than make a photo with that width and height thats the proper way or its obligatory to use 5300 X 3100

Comment: I used photoshop to create the size i want. I added it but now I want to change the opacity of the background image how can i do that... here is the html `<body class="standard-background-color standard-font-family" background="{% static '/images/background-1.png' %}">` here is the css `.standard-background-color {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}` but it chaged the opacity of the text not the image... @RadiantAhmed

Comment: if you want a background with opacity than it should be another div not on body tag because it will give the opacity to entire body by the way you can even make the picture with opacity in the photoshop

Answer (score 1):

As Radiant Ahmed pointed out in his comment, *if you want a background with opacity then it should be another div*

With that in mind, you can use a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to create the background image container.

Also there is no need to resize the actual image in Photoshop to fit the screen (though it's kinda huge), use `background-size: cover` instead.

How background-size property works [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

body::after {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://fillmurray.com/500/500');
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Yo! I'm the content!<p>
</div>
```

Comment: well i was just going to show him this way but i think am lil late..:P

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm assuming that you are trying to set the size for the background image for html which is unaffected by the CSS for body.

In that case, just add `!important` after what briancaffey said so that it doesn't get overridden by other CSS:

```
html {
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-attachment: fixed !important;
  background-position: center !important;
  -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
  -moz-background-size: cover !important;
  -o-background-size: cover !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
}
```

It's not recommendable to set a background size of 1920x1080, because people have different viewport sizes, so it's more practical to adjust the size to their viewport using `background-size: cover`.